# How does an rgb string, e.g., "rgb(255, 0, 0)" get converted into an actual color

Tags: javascript

I was following along an MDN article when I came across the following (more or less, with some minor modifications)

```
function random(min, max) {
  const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return num;
}

function Ball(x, y, velX, velY, color, size) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velX = velX;
  this.velY = velY;
  this.color = color;
  this.size = size;
}

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

Ball.prototype.update = function() {
  if (this.x + this.size >= width || this.x - this.size <= 0) {
    this.velX = -this.velX;
  }

  if (this.y + this.size >= height || this.y - this.size <= 0) {
    this.velY = -this.velY;
  }

  this.x += this.velX;
  this.y += this.velY;
}

while (balls.length < 25) {
  let size = random(10,20);
  let ball = new Ball(
    // ball position always drawn at least one ball width
    // away from the edge of the canvas, to avoid drawing errors
    random(0 + size,width - size),
    random(0 + size,height - size),
    random(-7,7),
    random(-7,7),
    "rgb(" + random(0,255) + ',' + random(0,255) + ',' + random(0,255) + ")",
    size
  );

  balls.push(ball);
}
```

Near the very bottom, there's an rgb string that uses random numbers to determine what color to make the balls. But it's just a string like "rgb(144, 96, 205)"; How does JavaScript know to convert that string into an actual rgb value? There doesn't seem to be anything in the code that is doing that.

Comment: It most likely add style via JS, and the style is interpreted as CSS by your browser.

Comment: @Nicolas Not sure what you mean, this is all of the JS, the HTML document is empty except for a canvas, and the CSS file is empty.

Comment: everything ends up being run by the browser. So if your canva draws a circle, and fill it blue. In the end, the browser would interpret it the same way it would interpret a background color. As CSS. I'm not so sure about your question, so i tried to explain the best i could.

Comment: An rgb string value is a valid color... so not sure what your question is about.

Comment: @Terry According to the canvas API? I've never worked with canvas before so I didn't know

Answer (score 1):

This `"rgb("[...]` string is passed as the `color` parameter of the Ball constructor, which itself is set as the `.color` property of the Ball instance, which in turn is used to set the [`ctx.fillStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle) in the `draw` method of the Ball instance.

It's when setting this `ctx.fillStyle` that the string is parsed as a CSS color.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To How does an rgb string, e.g., “rgb(255, 0, 0)” get converted into an actual color

```
function RGBToHex(rgb) {
  // Choose correct separator
  let sep = rgb.indexOf(",") > -1 ? "," : " ";
  // Turn "rgb(r,g,b)" into [r,g,b]
  rgb = rgb.substr(4).split(")")[0].split(sep);

  let r = (+rgb[0]).toString(16),
      g = (+rgb[1]).toString(16),
      b = (+rgb[2]).toString(16);

  if (r.length == 1)
    r = "0" + r;
  if (g.length == 1)
    g = "0" + g;
  if (b.length == 1)
    b = "0" + b;

  return "#" + r + g + b;
}
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.